# allow only certain chars in an input control

Tags: javascript, jquery, unobtrusive-validation

I am using jquery unobtrusive validation and my input looks like. so my input is allowed to have

```
<input class="FormElement form-control input-validation-error" data-val="true" data-val-required="The ID field is required." 
id="ID" name="ID" value="6" data-val-regex-pattern="^\d{1,12}(\.\d{0,3})?$|^\.\d{1,3}$" data-val-regex="You are allowed up to 12 digits in front of the decimal and 3 behind." aria-required="true" aria-invalid="true" aria-describedby="ID-error">
```

valid samples:

```
12
12.44
```

Invalid samples

```
12.3333333333333
12.
123456789045555.9
asdsadsadas
12.sw
```

The question is how do I disallow the user from even trying to enter values other than numbers and a period(.) before the validation catches it.

Comment: Just use regular expressions

Comment: _"Invalid samples:12."_ , _"valid samples:12.44"_ How would user be able to type `12.44` if `12.` is invalid?

Comment: I think it would be more user friendly to use the CSS3 pseudo selector `:invalid` to give the user feedback that their input is invalid instead of preventing them from entering in invalid info.

Answer (score 2):

There is a type attribute for the input element that you need to set to "number" like so:

```html
<input type="number" class="FormElement form-control input-validation-error" data-val="true" data-val-required="The ID field is required." 
id="ID" name="ID" value="6" data-val-regex-pattern="^\d{1,12}(\.\d{0,3})?$|^\.\d{1,3}$" data-val-regex="You are allowed up to 12 digits in front of the decimal and 3 behind." aria-required="true" aria-invalid="true" aria-describedby="ID-error">
```

Comment: This works in this particular case but how about if I am in countries where comma is used as a decimal separator? This does not allow me commas. So my question in general is how to prevent the user from entering unneeded chars using regex?

Comment: Then what you'd have to do is add an event handler for when a user presses a key and check what key they pressed.